# How do I fetch a cell value from a database and set it as default value within the dropdown list using angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

How do I fetch a cell value from a database and set it as default value within the dropdown list using angularjs?

This is my code:

```
<div class="form-group">
                        <label>Terms</label>
                        <select class="form-control" ng-options="item.ID as item.Name for item in PaymentTerms" ng-model="itm.ID_PaymentTerms">
                        </select>                             
</div>
```

Comment: where is the code ?

Comment: <div class="form-group">
       <label>Terms</label>
         <select class="form-control" ng-init="item.ID = data[2].id"  ng-options="item.ID as item.Name for item in PaymentTerms" ng-model="itm.ID_PaymentTerms">
               <option value="">--- Select an option ---</option>
                </select>

Comment: don't know what happened.. :\ sorry just the 2nd time doing this.

Comment: you can edit the post..

Comment: check this link   https://plnkr.co/edit/m4ov2ANe8uT7sphu48EQ?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

For default select drop down you need to set model value in the controller

```
<select class="form-control" ng-options="item.ID as item.Name for item in PaymentTerms" ng-model="itm.ID_PaymentTerms">
```

Coltroller:

```
$scope.itm.ID_PaymentTerms= $scope.PaymentTerms[2].ID;
```

For further details refer the link [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/m4ov2ANe8uT7sphu48EQ?p=preview)

Comment: ki bnda se ng ng ka chalaicho